React-native Expo prebuild failing. Error: " The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object"
After developing most of my app with react-native on expo, I've been trying to build it to check if it works by itself, but when prebuilding I'm running into this particular issue:
C:\Users\spippolator\React\myApp> npx expo prebuild
(node:25332) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
√ Created native directory | reusing /android
√ Updated package.json | no changes
× Prebuild failed
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: [android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: [android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
    at Object.resolve (node:path:171:9)
    at C:\Users\spippolator\React\myApp\node_modules\expo-font\plugin\build\utils.js:11:45
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveFontPaths (C:\Users\spippolator\React\myApp\node_modules\expo-font\plugin\build\utils.js:10:28)
    at C:\Users\spippolator\React\myApp\node_modules\expo-font\plugin\build\withFontsAndroid.js:15:70
    at action (C:\Users\spippolator\React\myApp\node_modules\@expo\config-plugins\build\plugins\withMod.js:201:29)
    at interceptingMod (C:\Users\spippolator\React\myApp\node_modules\@expo\config-plugins\build\plugins\withMod.js:105:27)
    at action (C:\Users\spippolator\React\myApp\node_modules\@expo\config-plugins\build\plugins\withMod.js:206:14)
    at async interceptingMod (C:\Users\spippolator\React\myApp\node_modules\@expo\config-plugins\build\plugins\withMod.js

I think it's probably related to how I manage fonts, but I've been looking at the documentation and I dont see the problem
But given that I'm new to this framework I'm sure I'm missing something
This is how I manage fonts:
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'font1': require('./assets/fonts/firstfont.otf'),
    'font2': require('./assets/fonts/secondfont.ttf'),
    'font3': require('./assets/fonts/thirdfont.ttf'),
    'font4': require('./assets/fonts/fourthfont.otf'),
    'font5': require('./assets/fonts/fifthfont.ttf'),
  });

I then declared variables so that I can reference these fonts throughout the code more easily.
const titleFont = 'font1';
const headerFont = 'font1';

I tried also loading fonts by:
import font1 from './assets/fonts/firstfont.otf';
import font2 from './assets/fonts/secondfont.ttf';
import font3 from './assets/fonts/thirdfont.ttf';
import font4 from './assets/fonts/fourthfont.otf';
import font5 from './assets/fonts/fifthfont.ttf';

//and later

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'font1': font1,
    'font2': font2,
    'font3': font3,
    'font4': font4,
    'font5': font5,
  });

but it doesn't change at all
And this is my app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myApp",
    "slug": "myApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.spippolator.myApp",
      "fonts": {
        "font1": "'./assets/fonts/fifthfont.ttf'",
        "font2": "./assets/fonts/secondfont.ttf",
        "font3": "./assets/fonts/thirdfont.otf",
        "font4": "./assets/fonts/fourthfont.ttf",
        "font5": "./assets/fonts/fifthfont.ttf"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "usesCleartextTraffic": true
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-font",
        {
          "fonts": [
            { 
              "fonts": "./assets/fonts/larabiefont-free.rg-regular.otf"
            },
            {
              "fonts": "./assets/fonts/SvBasicManual-nRPP.ttf"
            },
            {
              "fonts": "./assets/fonts/hackerchaos.otf"
            },
            {
              "fonts": "./assets/fonts/Hacked-KerX.ttf"
            },
            {
              "fonts": "./assets/fonts/GlitchGoblin-2O87v.ttf"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "987944a8-f07f-4599-857e-8734584802e4"
      }
    }
  }
}

When I start my build I also get this warning:
"WARN  fontFamily "font1" is not a system font and has not been loaded through expo-font."
I'm having a really hard time figuring this out, can anyone help me?
Thank you!
Tried changing fonts path, how I declare fonts, updating expo and some other stuff.
Also tried modifying app.json
Tried building a whole new project, still doesn't work.

In my app.json I've only added into plugins record "expo-font" so:
"plugins": [
      "expo-font",
      "other plugins..."
]

then in my _layout.tsx (you have App.js it's the same) I have the configuration shown above (that I use into an useEffect):
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export function App () {

const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    async function loadFont() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        "your_font_name": require("../assets/fonts/your_font.ttf"),
        "your_font_name": require("../assets/fonts/your_font.ttf"),
        "your_font_name": require("../assets/fonts/your_font.ttf"),
      });

      setFontLoaded(true);
    }

    loadFont();
  }, []);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return <Slot />;
  }
} 

Try to use loadAsync instead of useFonts because it can load a map of fonts. This returns a boolean if the fonts are loaded and ready to use. Obviously you can use your current font imports (mapping them correctly).
Let me know if it works.

This seems to be working, prebuild gives no errors for now!
I'll queue a build and I'll let you know if it works!

I'm not really sure. Prebuild goes on without any problems, but when I load the app in expo i still get the same error: "WARN fontFamily "font1" is not a system font and has not been loaded through expo-font."
The app works more or less fine, aside from a few text bugs here and there.
Problem is that now when I build the app, it builds without any errors or problems, but when launched it crashes instantly on startup.
I'm still trying to figure out if these two things are connected or not. Rn I'm trying to disable each package one by one but it takes a lot of time to re-build each time.

If it helps, try to run the app into Xcode or Android Studio (idk what is your device OS) because there the error logs are more clear and helpful then Expo Go... It's so strange. How do you use then the font name in styles ? Like fontFamily: "font1" ?

Yeah this is becoming a rabbit hole of problems. Turns out there were a few outdated components, so I got that fixed. The app now doesnt crash, but guess what it still doesnt work. Rn all I get is a white screen after loading, and ngl it's kinda hard to figure out whats wrong. I've installed adb to debug, but I dont really know how to set up my code so that it makes sense to debug through adb (I dont really know where to put console.error in my code to be debuggable lol)
